# Apparent contradiction in convexity of compositions of functions

Tags: convex-analysis

I offer a proposition with both a proof and a counterexample. Thus, either the proof is incorrect, or the counterexample is not actually a counterexample, or both. Which is it?

**Proposition.** Given a function $h(x)$ which is twice differentiable, strictly convex, and strictly decreasing, there does not exist a strictly increasing, twice differentiable function $g(y)$ such that $f(x) \equiv (g \circ h)(x)$ is concave.

**Proof.** Suppose $g(y)$ exists. By the properties of concave functions and the chain rule,

$$0 \geq f''(x) = (g \circ h)''(x) = [g'(h(x)) h'(x)]' = g'(h(x)) \underbrace{h''(x)}_{\gt 0} + {g''(h(x))} \underbrace{[h'(x)]^2}_{\gt 0}$$

For the statement to hold, we need $g'(h(x)) \leq 0 $ and $g''(h(x)) \leq 0$. Thus $g'$ must be weakly decreasing (and concave), a contradiction.

**Counterexample.** Consider $h(x) = \exp (-x)$ and $g(y) = \log  y$. $h$ is twice differentiable, convex, and strictly decreasing. $g$ is strictly increasing and twice differentiable. Finally, the function $f = (g \circ h)(x) = - x$ is linear, and therefore concave.

What's going on?

Comment: 1) In fact $f(x)=-x$. 2) a linear function can be consider as well as concave or convex...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your proof, you write

> For the statement to hold, we need $g'(h(x)) \leq 0 $ and $g''(h(x)) \leq 0$. Thus $g'$ must be weakly decreasing (and concave), a contradiction.

But, it really should read

> For the statement to hold, we need $g'(h(x)) \leq 0 $ **or** $g''(h(x)) \leq 0$. Thus $g'$ must either be weakly decreasing (a contradiction) or $g$ is concave. Oh well, I guess $g$ is concave, as per my counterexample.

Comment: If we are given $g'>0$, then can we additionally conclude that $g$ must be *strongly* concave, so that it it is "negative enough" to cancel out the positive first term in the expression for $f''$? I guess this would depend on the bounds of $h''$ and $g'$.

Comment: It would depend on the sizes of the various derivatives, indeed. I don't think you're going to get anything particularly general here.

Answer (score 0):

For the second derivative of $f\left(x\right)$, $g^\prime \left(h\left(x\right)\right) \leq 0 $ and $g^\prime \left(h\left(x\right)\right) \leq 0$ is sufficient condition of $f\left(x\right)^{\prime \prime} \leq 0$ but not necessary.